# Get latest Quantity update during the week by week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

An inventory gets updated for each warehouse during the week. The week starts from Wednesday (12:00:00 AM) to Tuesday (11:59:59 PM).

If I select October Month, it has 5 Wednesdays, 2nd October should have data from 25th Sept to 1st Oct.

- The warehouse can update inventory multiple times a week then get the latest inventory modified date
- If the warehouse didn't update the inventory, get the last inventory modified date for the new week.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE WarehouseUpdate
(
    WarehouseID INT
    ,WarehouseName VARCHAR(100)
    ,City VARCHAR(100)
    ,[State] VARCHAR(20)
    ,CurrentInventory INT
    ,ModifiedDate DATETIME2

)

SET @FromWed = DATEADD(DAY, - (DATEPART(dw, @ModifiedDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 4) % 7, @ModifiedDate);
SET @ToWed = DATEADD(DAY, - (DATEPART(dw, @ModifiedDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 4) % 7 + 7, @ModifiedDate);

INSERT INTO dbo.WarehouseUpdate
VALUES
(6541, 'XYZ','Huntsville','Alabama',658,'2019/10/07')
,(6541, 'XYZ','Huntsville','Alabama',941,'2019/10/08')
,(6417, 'ABC','Denver','Colorado',1001,'2019/09/26')
,(6541, 'XYZ','Huntsville','Alabama',745,'2019/09/29')
,(6589, 'JKL','Atlanta','Georgia',798,'2019/08/14')


/*Result should be for September 2019 (if the quantity is not updated for the warehouse, it should get CurrentInventory for last modified date), Inventory for Denver and Atlanta isn't updated after modified dates*/

For Wednesday 2nd
,(6541, 'XYZ','Huntsville','Alabama',745,'2019/09/29')
,(6417, 'ABC','Denver','Colorado',1001,'2019/09/26')
,(6589, 'JKL','Atlanta','Georgia',798,'2019/08/14')


For Wednesday 9th

(6541, 'XYZ','Huntsville','Alabama',941,'2019/10/08')
,(6417, 'ABC','Denver','Colorado',1001,'2019/09/26')
,(6589, 'JKL','Atlanta','Georgia',798,'2019/08/14')
```

Comment: A word of warning: define a separate and verifiable calendar table which maps days to weeks (running Wed-Tue, in this case). Performing complex date logic in a business query is a prescription for spaghetti code.

Comment: `If the warehouse didn't update the inventory...` can you explain this with suitable example and may be data.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment by @Steve: a typical solution to handle this would be involve creating a *calendar table*. That table would hold the start and end dates of each week (wednesday to tuesday). It should be quite easy to programatically generate the `insert` commands that will fill the table.

```
create table calendar(
    FromDate date primary key, 
    ToDate date
);
insert into calendar values 
    ('2019-09-25', '2019-10-01'), 
    ('2019-10-02', '2019-10-08'),
    -- ... more weeks ...
;
```

Once this table is in place, then you can simply `join` it with the inventory table, and use `row_number()` to keep only the latest record per week:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        w.*,
        row_number() over(partition by c.FromDate order by w.ModifiedDate desc) rn
    from calendar c
    inner join WarehouseUpdate w on w.ModifiedDate between c.FromDate and c.ToDate
) x
where rn = 1
```

---

Without a calendar table, you would need to dynamically compute the previous wednesday (using the expression that you provided, and that seems to work fine), and use that as a partitioning clause, like:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        w.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by 
                DATEADD(
                    DAY, 
                    - (DATEPART(dw, ModifiedDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 4) % 7, 
                    ModifiedDate
                ) 
            order by ModifiedDate desc
        ) rn
    from WarehouseUpdate w
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, there is catch in the business logic, if the inventory wasn't updated for the given week for the given warehouse, it should get the last inventory modified date.

Comment: @Justin, it sounds to me as though you just need the last inventory update date? Or is the idea that, given a reference date (which may be in the past), you want either the last inventory update date *which fell within the week which contains the reference date* (and which may be later than the reference date), or else you want the last inventory update date prior to the reference date? If it's the latter, then just use the calendar table to lookup the last day of the week in question, then get the inventory update date which falls on or before the last day of the week in question.

Comment: @Steve I have added what should result look like that would give you a clear idea.